# how to remove index.php in .htaccess file in codeiginator

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am a newbie at codeigniter.
When i access the url name `"http://abc/php/newseller/home/sign"` it is giving 404 error.  But when i access `http://abc/php/newseller/index.php/home/sign` then it will give the page. I want to remove "index.php" and my site should run with this url `"http://localhost/php/newseller/home/sign"` 
For this i tried in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And also remove index.php in application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

but getting the same problem of 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to change also this method in config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: yes but its not working. Also i want to tell that my .htaccess files is under muproject/application/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting in the config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

please remove an index.php file and the set the base URL it will work fine.

please try this htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Project Folder Name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|styles|vendor|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```